# Reading data from an Ubuntu terminal and storing it in different variables in C

Tags: c

I am writing a program that stores information of the iwscan Ubuntu command. I am actually reading properly the file that is created with the information; however, when trying to store data(ESSID in a string, Channel in an int and Quality in a double), I have several problems treating the strings to extract the data...

The code is as following:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char *tratarEssid(char *cadena);
int tratarCanal(char *cadena);
double tratarCalidad(char *cadena);
int tratarCanal(char *cadena){
    char resultado[2];
    strncpy(resultado,cadena+9,2);
    int canal;
    canal=atoi(resultado);
    return canal;
}
double tratarCalidad(char *cadena){
    char resultado[6];
    strncpy(resultado,cadena+8,6);
    char num[2];
    char den[2];
    strncpy(num,resultado,2);
    if(strlen(resultado)==5)
         strncpy(den,resultado+3,2);
    else
         strncpy(den,resultado+2,2);
    double numerador=atof(num);
    double denominador=atof(den);
    double calidad=numerador/denominador;
    return calidad;
 }
 char *tratarEssid(char *cadena){
      char *essid;
      essid=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
      strncpy(essid,cadena+7,10);
      return essid;
 }
 int main(){
    int i;
    const char *CHECKCANAL = "Channel:";
    const char *CHECKQUALITY = "Quality=";
    const char *CHECKESSID = "ESSID:";
    double calidad;
    int canal;
    char *essid;
    char cadena[20];
    system("iwlist wlan0 scan | egrep \"(Channel|Signal level|ESSID)\">/home/wein/Escritorio/basic/bin/Debug/Lista.txt");
    printf("Lista hecha\n");
    lista=fopen("Lista.txt","r");
    printf("Lista abierta\n");
    while (!feof(lista)){
            fgets(cadena,20,lista);
            printf("%s",cadena);
            if (strncmp(CHECKCANAL,cadena,strlen(CHECKCANAL))==0){
                canal=tratarCanal(cadena);
                printf("CANAL: %d\n",canal);
                }

             else if (strncmp(CHECKQUALITY,cadena,strlen(CHECKCANAL))==0){
                calidad=tratarCalidad(cadena);
                printf("CALIDAD: %f",calidad);
                }
             else if(strncmp(CHECKESSID,cadena,strlen(CHECKESSID))==0){
                essid=tratarEssid(cadena);
                printf("ESSID: %s\n",essid);
                }
      }
      return 0;
 }
```

So I know that my problem is in the conditionals made to filterig and treating the useful strings, just I don't know why the strncmp doesn't work properly (It should compare the beginning of the line with content of the String, or that's the idea) and thus, the functions don't work properly (Maybe I messed up in the functions as well...). Is there any other chance for treating the strings I receive correctly??

The output of the printf of the char[] cadena is just like this

```
Channel:11
Frequency:2.462 GH
z (Channel 11)
Quality=57/70  Sig
nal level=-53 dBm  
ESSID:"eduroam"
```

And I should be able to extract from there the ESSID, Quality and Channel.

Thanks for any idea/suggestion/help received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `strtok()` on cadena[] to divide the string into tokens as,

```
token[0]=strtok(cadena,"\n")  //considering the output you gave each date is in newline
token[1]=strtok(NULL,"\n")
token[2]=strtok(NULL,"\n")
token[3]=strtok(NULL,"\n")
token[4]=strtok(NULL,"\n")
token[5]=strtok(NULL,"\n")
```

then use `sscanf()` to get the required data from the token as,

```
sscanf(token[5],"ESSID:%s",ESSID);
sscanf(token[3],"Quality=%d/%d",&q1,&q2 )  //quality=q1/q2
sscanf(token[0],"Channel:%d",&channel)
```

this will give the required values from the string cadena[].

Comment: Since I am using fgets and only reads a line per time, I suppose it is posible to use a blank space as delimiting character, isn't it?? Should be like this: token[0]=strtok(cadena," "); token[1]=strtok(NULL," "); etc...

Comment: @DaniWein ya. delimeter can be anything. strtok() will break the string based on that delimeter. so you can use space too.

Answer (score 0):

Your [`strncpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) function calls don't add the terminator to the strings you copy to. Besides, they are to small to contain the terminator.

That means that when you call functions such as `atoi` on an unterminated string it will cause *undefined behavior*, as the function continues beyond the end of the allocated memory.

Comment: Ok, that means I should make the char[] a little bit bigger in order to add '\0' character before using atoi and atof.